# Attaching unique identifier to Sharepoint Metadata lookup fields

Tags: 2010

Any idea on how we can store unique identifier along with the Metadata on the SharePoint taxonomy?

I have stored data coming from CRM database into as Taxonomy Metadata inside SharePoint.  These metadata are part of lookup fields on a calendar event.  The request is to send back any edits inside the Calendar along with the CRM data involved but to be identified by their CRM IDs and not their names.  Eg., John Doe is not good since there might more than one John Doe in the CRM database.

Looking on how to achieve this in SharePoint 2010 out-of-box without much coding involved.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for storing the extra data:

- You can store it in the Description field for the term
- You can store it as a CustomPropery in the term using [SetCustomProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.term.setcustomproperty)

Comment: Yes, I can store extra data easily. However when I choose John Doe from Metadata, what views can I create and/or how I can expose this additional data - such that John Doe coming from SharePoint Managed Metadata goes into CRM identified by his unique ID?